# Move an ESXi 5 image to anohter server

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-esxi

I have an ESXi 5 server with two large VMs.  Both have several snapshots that have accumulated over time.  I set up another ESXi to use as a backup system, but I am having trouble getting the images to run on the second server.

I tried to copy the VM from the datastore to another ESXi server, but when I try to start it, I get an error that it can't find some files (it is looking in a specific directory with a GUID.)  From my research, it appears that it is looking for the snapshot files, and can't find them on the new server.

What is the best way to bring up the VMs on the new ESXi?

I have seen a method where the snapshots are merged, creating a single file.  The documentation says that it can take a long time, and the ESXi shouldn't be touched during this time.  Is this the best way?  How dangerous is it, say if the process were interrupted in the middle?  Can the original image still be used?  Is it all or nothing?

Or, can I make a directory in the new datastore, and try and assign it the expected GUID?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just to mention, snapshots are not necessarily a reliable form of a backup. Please refer to this article [http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025279]. Maybe consider using VeeAm backup (extremely reliable), and you'll know you are safe.

Comment: "snapshots accumulated over time"=massive alarm bells! Don't do this please, we never keep a snapshot for more than 24hrs, just clone the VMs instead, or back them up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this work by exporting as a OVF template and deploy the VM using the template in second ESXi. Anyway this OVF can be useful for future uses(in case of disasters) as well. Mostly the Admins prefer this option and there is nothing to fear about! If the export interrupts, you can start afresh and the source VM will not be disturbed.

HTH!